# Gets and sets not updating objects

Tags: c++, pointers, singleton

I've created a singleton object which holds a bunch of lists. Mainly, a vector list which holds player objects.

this allows me to send a list of players between classes.

however, when I try to edit information in these Player objects, such as the score or turns, it doesn't allow me to do so.

**Code example and output:**

```
u.CreateStaticPlayers();    
cout << "turns" << d->getPlayers().at(1).getTurns() << endl;
d->getPlayers().at(1).setTurns(3);  
cout << "turns" << d->getPlayers().at(1).getTurns() << endl;
cout << "score" << d->getPlayers().at(1).getScore() << endl;
d->getPlayers().at(1).setScore(11);     
cout << "score" << d->getPlayers().at(1).getScore() << endl;
```

**Output**

```
turns 100
turns 100 score 501 score 501
```

**Expected output**

```
turns 100 turns 3 score 501 score 11
```

Any advice on what I might be doing wrong?

these are just standard gets and sets. The gets and sets are correct I believe.

**Gets and sets as requested**

```
int & Player::getTurns()
{
    return turns;
}

int &Player::getScore()
{
    return score;
}

void  Player::setScore(int i)
{
    score = i;
}

void  Player::setTurns(int i)
{
    turns = i;
}
```

**PLAYER CLASS HEADER**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Player
{

private:

    int ID;
    string name;


    //signifies whether this player is human or not (default 0)
    bool isHuman = 0;

    //this array holds the current turns the AI wants to perform.
    //the array is recalculated whenever a new turn takes place IF the AI doesn't get what it expected to hit.
    //set calculated pushes one new value onto the array.
    //get calulated returns the entire array.
    vector<int> calculatedturns;

    //a score that starts at 501, and approaches 0 as the GUI progresses. 
    //The score decreases and the AI calculates a movement path so we need the ability to GET and SET
    int score = 501;


    //current darts starts at 3 when the round begins, acts like a counter and a trigger, decreases to 0, and then resets back to 3 at the start of a new round.
    //the dart number flucuates from 0-3 so we need the ability to GET and SET.
    int darts = 3;

    //the amount of rounds the GUIs has currently played,
    //we need a GET and SET because the GUIs increases, and we need to display them to the user.
    int games = 0;


    //the amount of rounds the sets has currently played,  
    //we need a GET and SET because the sets increases, and we need to display them to the user.
    int sets = 0;

    //the amount of darts the player has currently thrown. 
    //we need a GET and SET because the throws increases, and we need to display them to the user.
    int turns = 100;

    //Will determine if the player has actually won the GUI.
    //we need to get the current state to determine certain events have taken place, so we need a GET and a SET.
    bool has_won = false;

    //Will determine if the player has finished the GUI.
    //we need to get the current state to determine certain events have taken place, so we need a GET and a SET.
    bool has_finished = false;

    //the hit accuracy is predefined for a player, and does not change, it requires a GET and SET.
    int hit_accuracy = 0;

    //hits needs to be incremented and displayed
    //we need a GET and SET. 
    int total_hits = 0;

    //misses needs to be incremented and displayed
    //we need a GET and SET. 
    int total_misses = 0;

public:
    Player();

    /////GETTERS///////

    string &getName();
    int &getID();
     int &getScore();
     int &getAccuracy();
     int &getDarts();
     int &getGames();
     int &getSets();
     int &getTurns();
     bool &getWon();
     bool &getFinished();
     int &getHits();
     int &getMisses();
     vector<int> &getCalculated();


     /////SETTERS//////

     void setName(string s);
     void setID(int i);
     void setScore(int i);
     void setAccuracy(int i);
     void setDarts(int i);
     void setGames(int i);
     void setSets(int i);
     void setTurns(int i);
     void setWon(bool i);
     void setFinished(bool i);
     void setHits(int i);
     void setMisses(int i);
     void setCalculated(int i);


     ////CONSTRUCTORS////

     Player(int ID, string name, int Accuracy);


     ////METHODS///

     //at the start of the game, score is 501.
     //AI must find a way to get score to 60.
     int Player::AI_CALCULATE_TURN(int currentscore);
```

**PLAYER CPP**

```
#include "Player.h"


//player class is needed because there is more than one player that requires the same information.
//player class holds crucial data about the player, including their current darts, current score, current GUIplan and other things.



Player::Player()
{
}




////GETTERS/////


string & Player::getName()
{
    return name;
}

int & Player::getID()
{
    return ID;
}

int &Player::getScore()
{
    return score;
}

int &Player::getAccuracy()
{
    return hit_accuracy;
}

int &Player::getDarts()
{
    return darts;
}

int & Player::getGames()
{
    return games;
}

int & Player::getSets()
{
    return sets;
}

int & Player::getTurns()
{
    return turns;
}

bool & Player::getWon()
{
    return has_won;
}

bool & Player::getFinished()
{
    return has_finished;
}

int & Player::getHits()
{
    return total_hits;
}

int & Player::getMisses()
{
    return total_misses;
}

vector<int>& Player::getCalculated()
{
    return calculatedturns;
}


////SETTERS/////


void Player::setName(string s)
{
    name = s;
}

void  Player::setID(int i)
{
    ID = i;
}
void  Player::setScore(int i)
{
    score = i;
}

void  Player::setAccuracy(int i)
{
    hit_accuracy = i;
}
void  Player::setDarts(int i)
{
    darts = i;
}
void  Player::setGames(int i)
{
    games = i;
}
void  Player::setSets(int i)
{
    sets = i;
}
void  Player::setTurns(int i)
{
    turns = i;
}
void Player::setWon(bool i)
{
    has_won = i;
}
void  Player::setFinished(bool i)
{
    has_finished = i;
}
void  Player::setHits(int i)
{
    total_hits = i;
}
void  Player::setMisses(int i)
{
    total_misses = i;
}

void  Player::setCalculated(int i)
{
    calculatedturns.push_back(i);
}

Player::Player(int id, string Name, int accuracy)
{
     name= Name;
     ID = id;
     hit_accuracy = accuracy;
}


////METHODS

int Player::AI_CALCULATE_TURN(int currentscore)
{
    //score is 501, but it could be anything.
    //if score is above 60, the AI should be picking a number from the board arrays, it should aim for the higher number possible.

    if (currentscore > 60)
    {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

**LIST CLASS CPP **

```
#include "List.h"

//initilizaing the instance.

List* List::theList = NULL;


List * List::getInstance()
{
    //will create a new instance if it currently doesn't exist.

    if (theList == NULL)
    {
        theList = new List();
    }
    return theList;

}

void List::destroyInstance()
{
    //deleting the instance
    delete theList;

    //set the value to null, program won't crash when destructor is called again.
    theList = NULL;
}


int List::getExample()
{
    return exampleint;
}

vector<Player>List::getPlayers()
{
    return PLAYERS_LIST;
}

vector<Player> List::getFinished()
{
    return FINISHED_LIST;
}

void List::addPlayer(Player player)
{
    PLAYERS_LIST.push_back(player);
}

void List::addFinished(Player player)
{
}


void List::setExample(int i)
{
    exampleint = i;
}

List::List()
{
}


List::~List()
{
}
```

**LIST CLASS HEADER**

```
    #pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

//my attempt at a singleton object.
class List
{
public:

    //this will create the SINGLE instance
    //need to be static because we want to call them if the object doesn't exist
    static List* getInstance();

    static void destroyInstance();

    ////getters///
    vector<Player> getPlayers();
    vector<Player> getFinished();
    int getExample();




    //basically a setter, pushes a player onto the back of the players list. (to signifiy they're playing)
    void addPlayer(Player players);
    //basically a setter, pushes a player onto the back of the finished list. (to signify they're finished)
    void addFinished(Player player);
    void setExample(int i);




private:

    //shouldn't be able to call these, prevents the creation of a new instance.
    List();
    ~List();

    //the instance itself.

    static List* theList;


    //players list holds all of the players currently in the game.
    vector<Player> PLAYERS_LIST;

    //finished list holds the players that have finished the game.
    vector<Player> FINISHED_LIST;


    int exampleint = 0;

};
```

Comment: "these are just standard gets and sets." Please post the code anyway.

Comment: You must have an error somewhere in your code.

Comment: posted gets;sets; no visible error.

Comment: pretty sure there's no issue with the gets and sets.

Comment: Okay, so you've shown code that works. That must mean that the problem is somewhere else. Most of the code you've shown is irrelevant to the problem. Chop it out, reduce it to the smallest piece of code you can come up with that compiles, runs, and shows the problem. There's a good chance that you'll spot the problem yourself when you do that. If not, post the code.

Comment: This is the smallest piece of code; I put a breakpoint in -- the set takes in the 3 and turns becomes 3, however the subsequent getturns() shows 100 again, like that set never took place.

Comment: Are `getTurns`/`setTurns` and `getScore`/`setScore` the only getters/setters affected, or are others returning unexpected results as well? I half wonder if your `d->getPlayers()` call is somehow resetting your player, or returning an entirely new one.

Comment: I believe all variables in the class are affected in the same way, maybe it's something to do with my list class? I posted the code.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be affecting every variable, no idea what's up here, any ideas?

Comment: addplayer pushes players onto the back of the list, PLAYERS_LIST is defined in the List header, any help would be greatly appreciated.

does the fact the list is static mean anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getter is wrong:

```
vector<Player> List::getPlayers();
```

When you use it in the following manner:

```
d->getPlayers().at(1).setTurns(3);
```

You are actually affecting a *copy*.  You do not modify the actual players held in your object.

Make it return a reference:

```
vector<Player> & List::getPlayers();
//        here ^
```